# Is it possible to connect security IP camera by wired connection to drone's flight controller and transmit this video by VTX?

Tags: flight-controller, video-transmitters, camera

I'm seeking for camera that I can use on gimball of my selfmade drone. This variant https://vi.aliexpress.com/item/1005003252272933.html looks as ideal solution but I'm not sure that I can use it with Flight Controller (Ardupilot) and VTX.
Is it possible? Could I control zoom remotely? Will the video fit the radio channel?

It's a second camera. I have swither that can switch video between main camera and additional. So, delays is not a big problem.